# Linear ODE conversion via substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I forgot my ODE's. I need to convert the following into linear with constant coefficients via substitution. Need to know what I am subbing for $x$:

$xy''+y'=\frac{1}{x}$

any hint or tip would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: A thought: dividing by $x$ gives a $1/x$ term and it's derivative $1/x^2$ up to a sign. So perhaps try $v'=y'/x$, which leads to $v''=y''/x -y'/x^2$. So $xv''=y'' - y'/x=y'' - v'$... There are also other methods besides substitution to solve here.

Comment: Try $x=e^t$ $  $